# How to stream a video file with WebRTC?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc

I would like to stream a video file selected through the input file to a peer using WebRTC.

Details:
I would like to use the addstream method instead of the data channel for this purpose.

In my code I generated a blob from the file, like this:

```
localVideo.src =  window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

It plays correctly locally.

But I also would like to stream this video to a  peer.

Then I try to generate a MediaStream from the blob to use it as parameter of the method addstream.

None of these methods works on chrome Version 37.0.2062.120 (64-bit)

```
localVideo.captureStream

localVideo.createMediaElementSource

localVideo.captureStreamUntilEnded

localVideo.stream

localVideo.srcObject

localStream.mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded
```

Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: [This may give you some direction](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pre-recorded-Media-Streaming/). Note, that I do not believe that there is a implementation in Chrome as of yet. Also, `mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded` is in FireFox only.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Use a data connection and push each frame and then play each frame on the other side.
2. If you are in firefox, you could try `mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded`

There is no implementation in Chrome that is built for streaming a video file as a MediaStream as of yet.

[Muaz Kahn WebRTC Experiments](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pre-recorded-Media-Streaming/) has a small script that should simplify this for you. It takes into account both options.